KeggScape Network Import Issue
Whenever I try to import an xgml file in cytoscape the file shows gibberish nodes like some form of code for example eco 234 all the nodes have similar codes like this instead of the actual name of the molecules in my network. How do I fix this?
Update: Hello there as of 26/10/24, there has been an update for Cytoscape to the version 3.10.3. If you are updated and all including having the updated keggscape app, try uninstalling keggscape and reinstalling the latest version and I can now confirm that the pathways are showing up as expected thankyou for all the help.
ANOTHER UPDATE 10/30/2024: SO the networks are showing up as expected individually but when I merge them the same problem is occuring. Please help again.

Keggscape is not correctly installing the style.  We're aware of the problem and are working on it...and have now just fixed it.
Please install the latest version.

Can you kindly described the versions where the bug was discovered and the version where it was fixed? The reason is that each post exists long after the posting date and thus will be a reference to others.
